# Strange Android behaviour while writing to /dev/hid device

Tags: java, android, linux, security, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to write some data to `/dev/hidg0` file (USB-HID device), that file has 777 file rights.
 
Unfortunately, when trying to execute `write()` method, device hangs and I can't find out why.
 BTW, on my main phone everything is OK, but I have now another one specially for this app. It is not rooted, but "sz" command in shell grants me root access through terminal session.
method looks like this:

```
File f = new File("/dev/hidg0");
//returns "true true true"
System.out.println(f.canRead() + " " + f.canWrite() + " " + f.canExecute()); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
byte[] to_send = new byte[] {0,0,0x21,0,0,0,0,0};
fos.write(to_send, 0, to_send.length);
```

From DDMS I managed to take stack trace:

> at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
>   at
>   libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:178)
>   at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:191)
>   at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:457)
>   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
>   at
>   ru.mastergroosha.hidapp.Main.sendKeys(Main.java:101)
>   at
>   ru.mastergroosha.hidapp.Main.onClick(Main.java:143)
>   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
>   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
>   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And breakpoint shows the following info:

[image: breakpoint]

I can see some words with "Guard" part but can't find out what role does it play here. Could you help me understand my problem?

Comment: Please add the error output from logcat.

Comment: @Chris there's no error in logs! App just hangs. I set up `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` but it's still empty.

Comment: You have excessively trimmed the logs.  What is the type of the exception?  You have only posted the stack trace.

Comment: @Chris, This is not exception! No exception is shown via LogCat, nothing happens, just phone hangs. The only thing I can do is to enter DDMS and see stack. I'll post video/screenshots later.

Comment: Ok.  What you are writing to is not a literal file, but a kernel driver.  It's possible for a kernel driver to fail to return from a call - in fact that is used to advantage for certain types of I/O reads that block until an external condition triggers an interrupt.  That this write would block seems a bit odd, but are you sure that trying to write to this node is even legitimate?  Does it need configuration first?   **What *exactly* are you hoping to accomplish by this write operation**.  What driver owns that node, and what peripheral is connected?   Don't be vague, be explicit.